# Manim not outputting anything

Tags: testing, installation, manim

I'm trying to get Manim working, and I've missed something - but I'm not sure what. I've followed verbatim the instructions [here](https://talkingphysics.wordpress.com/2020/07/06/clean-install-of-manim/), and the installation seems to have gone fine. If I try `pip install manimlib`  I get a list of `Requirement already satisfied`. But, if I run the example `python3 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl`, nothing happens. No error, no output, just nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZj_GQc6pN4&t=205s), it's excellent. Also, make sure you run the command in the Manim directory, or it won't find the file.

Comment: This video sadly does not work anymore, could you please update the link?

Comment: Hi, the link was for an older version of Manim. Here's a link for a 2022 tutorial for Windows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYOLQk8GpME. Manim Community Edition has good documentation and installation instructions at https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation.html